# Mysql - Convert local date in UTC format

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I am having mysql dates stored in this format :

[image]

In my sql query I want to get these dates in UTC format. 
I have tried CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)function but I cannot determine how can I get from_tz for the dates. I know that to_tz will be 'UTC' or '+0000'

Comment: You can refer this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select convert_tz(`date`, replace(substring_index(`date`, ' ', -1), '00', ':00'), '+00:00')
```

***Edit:***

```
select convert_tz(`date`, concat(left(substring_index(`date`, ' ', -1), 3), ':', right(substring_index(`date`, ' ', -1), 2)), '+00:00')
```

Comment: It was working untill I found timestamps like these : 2017-04-17 09:21:33 +0530... In which case its giving NULL

Comment: yup! That would do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mysql ignores TZ qualifiers in date, I suggest you do a semimanual TZ conversion

```
select         
    date_add("2017-04-18 15:15:15  +1000", interval substring("2017-04-18 15:15:15 +1000", -5, 3) hour),
    date_add("2017-04-18 15:15:15  +1000", interval substring("2017-04-18 15:15:15 -1000", -5, 3) hour)
;
```

the result will be in UTC timezone as you expect

Comment: This is a good approach, however it always adds the time even though the local time zone is +0600 in which case it should actually subtract the time.